# iOS app crashing in iOS 10 (working in iOS 11)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10

My iOS app is working successfully in iOS 11, but unfortunately is crashing when showing the splash screen in iOS 10.

I have attached the device log, any ideas?

Thanks, N

Device Log:
[iPhone 5 iOS 10.0.2 Device log - CRASH](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qssd9ctdwx9c20j/iOS10-crash-log.txt?dl=0)

Comment: Can you please symbolicate the crash log?

Comment: You are getting an unrecognized selector. Are you using any new API's that might not be available in iOS 10?

Comment: Did you debug it on which line it crashes?

Comment: You need to symbolicate your crash log in order to find the line in your code where the crash occurred

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your quick responses. Will get a symbolicated crash log and try to debug on the device. Will let you know how I go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Obviously this does not working in versions older than iOS 11.

```
if (context.BiometryType == LABiometryType.TypeFaceId)
```